# Running an exe from electron-angular9

Tags: angular, electron

I have an electron-angular9(not js) project and I want to run an console app with some parameters from the electron application.

Is it possible? If yes , how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, by using IpcMain and ElectronService.
Basically what we do is to send a message from the chromiu process to the electron process, as the chromiu process isn't cable of running an exe file from your local machine because its a security issue and therefor its blocked by design from doing it.
Once the electron process gets the massege it can call the executable with the desired parameters.

In the main.js file where we start our entire app need to define :

```
 const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

 ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
     let executablePath = ".\\my.exe";
     var child = require('child_process').execFile;
     child(executablePath, arg, function (err, data) {
         console.log(data.toString());
         event.returnValue = data;
     });
 
 });
```

and in the angular project where you want to send `synchronous-message` :

```
 import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
 
 constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) {}
 
 public CallExe(){
    var parameters = [ this is the parameters array];
     var pong = this._electronService.ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message',parameters);
     console.log(pong);
 }
```